# How do I mute foobar2000 when Windows is locked?

Tags: windows-7, audio, foobar2000, mute

I find strange that my Windows 7 continues playing music it is locked.
I would like that it be mute in that state, or at least that it stops/pauses the music player.
How to configure it?
I use foobar2000 as my music player

Comment: Locked is not the same as sleeping. Lock prevents external user input - it doesn't stop processes from running. Are you sure you don't really want to put your computer to sleep?

Comment: locked != locked up

Comment: @Dennis corrected

Comment: @PP good idea, maybe it is what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Mute On Lock:

> **[Mute On Lock](http://www.superutils.com/products/mute-on-lock/key.)** is a tiny resident utility that sits in the
>   system tray and monitors your session:
>   when you are locking your Windows
>   workstation, it mutes the sound of
>   your speakers. With the help of this
>   program you can quickly mute or unmute
>   the system sound by double-clicking
>   the tray icon or using an optional hot
>   key.

[image]

It's free and run from Windows XP to Windows 7 (including 64-bit editions).

Comment: It didn't work for me on Win7 64bit

Comment: Did you try to use the 'Windows Compatibility mode' set to Windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using foobar2000 you can use this foobar plugin

[Pause On Lock](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_lock)

> Adds the menu command "Pause On Lock" which will automatically pause playback when the desktop is locked or when a Fast User Switch occurs, then resume when the desktop session is restored.

[image]