# Is there a way to continue playback when the screen is turned off?

Tags: windows-10, audio, foobar2000

I seem to have kind of the opposite problem as the one described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/195620/how-do-i-mute-foobar2000-when-windows-is-locked).

I am running foobar2000 (1.3.9) on my Windows 10 convertible laptop. When the screen turns off, either because the system was idle for a while, or because I press the lock button of the device, playback is automatically paused. It resumes as soon as I turn the screen back on (even when I'm still on the lockscreen).

Is there a way to have payback continue even when the device is locked?

Comment: Is this issue related to foobar2000, in particular, or generally to each application that plays back audio files?

Comment: Check the power settings: make sure the computer is not set to sleep at the same time as the screen is switched off.

Comment: @daniel.neumann I'd really like to continue using foobar, seeing that it does exactly what I want from a music player.

Comment: @AFH Good call. I just checked, and it's going into "energy savings mode". Apart from disabling the button completely, there is no "lighter" setting than that.

Comment: I just found the related http://superuser.com/questions/516188/how-to-turn-off-the-display-in-windows-8-without-locking-or-making-computer-go-t Going by that question, it doesn't look too good.

Comment: `Is there a way to have payback continue even when the device is locked?` - What would be the point? Is this just so you can pretend you listened to some boring lecture notes because ifr so, you're lying to yourself he he he :) Generally, can I ask why you want this behaviour as it may provide more insight and thus other solutions

Comment: @Dave I'm basically looking for a way to continue playback when the screen is turned off, similar to how it works on a phone. The problem is that turning off the screen locks the device at the same time.

Comment: You can try it with the button and lid disabled for power, at least while plugged in. You will find out soon enough if this is the problem.

Comment: @MrLemmon Did you already find a solution to this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You must Disable Connected Standby on your convertible laptop. But keep in mind it will drain your battery faster. Because it will allow desktop applications to run in background.

How to disable:

1. Tap on the Windows-key, type regedit.exe and hit the Enter-key.
2. Navigate to the key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power
3. Locate the preference CsEnabled on the right side.
4. Double-click on it, and set its value to 0.
5. Restart the PC.

More info at this [article](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/09/13/play-music-on-a-surface-while-the-screen-is-off/)